# Receiving TCP data from WiFi Scales

Tags: networking, tcp, listen

I am essentially trying to take an existing WiFi scale and develop a program to process received data.  The scales I am looking at have existing software and ideally at the end of this project I will have replaced their software with my own.  I have developed some basic network communication programs in the past but for this project I would likely need to understand how the device and PC are communicating.

I haven't really used Telnet or PuTTy before but is it possible to use these programs to listen to the connection and show all incoming and outgoing data?

This is the scale I'm looking at http://www.withings.com/en/bodyscale
and I'm hoping that they use HID-Point of Scale

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY is a SSH-client for Windows. you can't listen traffic using PuTTY. 
Telnet is a Telnet-client. You can conect to TCP ports with client and communicate with services that have plain-text protocol. I suppose that telnet is also useless in your case.

Sniffing and traffic analysis is a bad idea in this case. But if you want you can do it with tcpdump, tshark, wireshark and so on.

As far as I understand, bodyscale uses some web-based API to retransmit its data direct to a web-service. I suppose that you can get this data from the service later (after they are retransmitted).

Answer (score 0):

Having taken a look at their user guide for the scale it doesn't look like you can set the server that the scale talks to and there seems to be no sign of a message spec/API doc which details the protocol that the scale talks. This will make it a little more complicated.

I'd start by setting up Wireshark and sniff the communications that the scale performs. Then you could decode the protocol it's using, which is probably pretty simple. You can the write a server that understands the protocol. The final step is get the scale to talk to your server rather than theirs; this will probably require that you set up your own dns server and have that resolve the domain name that the scale attempts to connect to so that it points to the machine on which you're running your server.

An alternative would be to write a custom packet analysis/capture program using WinPcap (or similar) and then just sniff the communication between the scale and their server and write your own data collector/processor that deals with the sniffed data.

They may provide an API that you can use to extract the data from their server/site after your scale has uploaded it and this may turn out to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Was researching this myself today and found this: https://github.com/damonachey/Withings
I realise it's 4 years later, and not exactly what you were asking, but might give you the expected result?